# What does 'VL' stand for in 'Windows Server 2003 Web Edition with SP1 - VL'

Tags: windows-server-2003

On the MSDN downloads I can see both:

- Windows Server 2003 Web Edition with SP1 - VL
- Windows Server 2003 Web Edition with SP1

What's that difference & which should I use?

Comment: I believe if you look around that M$ website you will find the answer.

Comment: In theory, but searching for `VL` was a little fruitless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VL stands for "Volume License", and you need if you have a VL key.

What you should use is "None". Win 2003 Server will be out of service in a year and it doesn't make any sense to start any project with this old piece of software.

Comment: Cheers SvW, I guess it makes no different which one then.  I'm not developing anything new for it, just need to check new stuff is compatible with it as work has quite a few still in play.

Comment: More generally to the "should I use a VL version?" question: You should only use a VL version if you've paid for it.  Although, my understanding (which may not be correct, so you should really ask your MSDN rep) is that if you have an MSDN account that gives you access to a VL of [product(s)] then you're allowed to use it/them as such.

Comment: @Ryan Correct, specifically purchasing MSDN on a volume licence agreement (this is worth it even with only a single subscription because it is cheaper than retail purchase of MSDN) gives you access to VL downloads and keys. *However* after XP/2003 things changed (to KMS based).